# Is there a way to get ideavim to work in the IntelliJ database console?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

When I activate the ideavim plugin in IntelliJ while editing files I get Vim emulation that I expect.  When I activate it within a database console window, it changes the cursor to the block cursor but none of the Vim emulation is active.  Is there anyway to get the Vim emulation to work within the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see that a bug has been filed.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-740

A work around is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to exit insert mode.